# Any interface for building a server in Linux Xubuntu. (not desktop)

Tags: server, xubuntu, gnome-terminal, gui, interface

Is there any interface or program that I could install on my Linux Xubuntu that would help me set up a server using the terminal as little as possible?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by interface? For most people the command line (over SSH if remote access is required) is plenty.

Xubuntu is made up of all the same packages as Ubuntu (as is Ubuntu Server). Anything you can do in one of them (eg `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`) will work in the other.